# Como faço para uma check box ficar "checked" quando entro com valores em 2 campos dinamicamente?

Tags: php, html, laravel, checkbox

Como faço para que os checkbox se marquem quando o usuário inserir valores nos dois campos?

```
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" ><input type="number" max="20" min="0"  size="1" maxlength="2" name="<?php echo 'scorea'.$n; ?>" value="{{ old('scorea' . $n) }}" > </td>
<td> X </td>
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"> <input type="number" max="20" min="0"  size="1" maxlength="2" name="<?php echo 'scoreb'.$n; ?>" value="{{ old('scoreb' . $n) }}" ></td>
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">  <?php echo $c->timeb; ?> </td>
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">  <?php echo $c->campeonato; ?> </td>
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"> <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="<?php echo 'jogo'.$n; ?>" VALUE="true">
  </tr>
```

Comment: Os dois campos devem ser preenchidos para marcar o checkbox? E é realmente necessário criar os campos com esses nomes? Se representam a mesma coisa, não seria mais conveniente armazená-los em um campo com nome `scoreA[]` e `scoreB[]`, criando uma lista de valores?

Comment: não, pois é um loop.... e pode aparecer 'n' linhas. então quero que sejam marcadas somente os checkbox dos inputs preenchidos.

Comment: Coloca mais exemplo do seu código, de preferencia onde ocorre o loop!